# Reading Blob of a file in javascript and inserting in database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, string, blob

I want to read any kind of file from my js code and insert its blob to database in long blob type column. Variable in js is reading blob as string but not as blob.

So I am facing issue if there are special characters like single/double quote etc.

reading code is

```
function onChooseFile(event, onLoadFileHandler) {
if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function')
    throw ("The file API isn't supported on this browser.");
let input = event.target;
if (!input)
    throw ("The browser does not properly implement the event object");
if (!input.files)
    throw ("This browser does not support the `files` property of the file input.");
if (!input.files[0])
    return undefined;
let file = input.files[0];
let fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = onLoadFileHandler;
fr.onloadend = function(event) {
  if (event.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
    //blobData = event.target.result;
    blobData = new Blob([event.target.result], { type: fileType });

    console.log(blobData);
    console.log(typeof(blobData));
    console.log(blobData instanceof Blob) 
    console.log("-------------------------------------------------");

    blobString = ab2str(event.target.result);
    console.log(blobData);
    alert("file read complete "+blobData.length);
  }
};
document.getElementById('inputHeader').value = file.name;
  fileName = file.name;
  fileType = file.type;
  fileExtension = fileName.split(".").pop();
  fr.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Writing Code is

```
dataservice.openDocument(document_version_id)
            .done(function (reply) {
                fileExtension = fileName.split(".").pop();
                switch(fileExtension.toLowerCase()){
                    case "doc":
                    case "docx":
                    fileType = "application/msword";
                    break;
                    case "pdf":
                    fileType = "application/pdf";
                    break;
                    case "xls":
                    case "xlsx" :
                    fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                }

                var blob = new Blob([reply.RECORD_DATA.LONG_BLOB], { type: fileType });
                saveAs(blob, 'C:/OutputFile/hello.'+fileExtension);
                deferred.resolve();
            }).fail(function (error) {
                alert("failure in getting document");
                deferred.reject();
            });
        });
```

Please help, how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the JavaScript that you have tried at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you sure it is an instance of a blob? Try logging: `console.log(MyBlob instanceof Blob)`. Does it return true or false?

Comment: @Stretch0 it is returning true